# Is there an easy way to import textured 3D geometry from Maya into Nuke?

Tags: 3d, maya, nuke

I have a room with a number of objects inside it, many of which are duplicated, and I've managed to transfer the room as a single object into Nuke, and then attach its texture as a separate read node attached to the readGeo node, but any time I try to export more than one object, even if it's just another instance of the same object, the import fails to show all objects.

Do I need to import every single object separately (around 30 objects total) or is there an easier way to do this that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 2):

This still isn't as easy as it should be, but the way forward is to export your geometry as Alembic.  It supports many textured objects, and even animated sequences.  Depending on your version of Maya, you may need to install a plugin, but it is much better than dealing with OBJ and FBX as the interchange format in most cases.